# Miniconda has multiple versions of libraries installed

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I checked out the pkgs folder of my Miniconda installation and found that some of the libraries has multiple versions installed. 
[Miniconda Package Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8s8o.png)

I did not install seperate versions and I am not using virtualenv. All my projects use the base interpreter. I would like to know why this is happening and uninstall all the versions except the latest one.

Comment: Kindly add a comment before downvoting as to explain why you did downvote

Answer (score 0):

These versions are not installed, they are cached versions of old packages that have been upgraded. You can clean them with

```
conda clean --tarballs --packages
```

Comment: I did try this and it did not remove the older packages

Comment: Then those packages must be installed in an environment. Conda will only remove cached package files that are not installed in any environment.

Comment: I did not create any seperate environments. Does Anaconda create any such environments? I am the sole user of this system and no one else could have created this environment.